# Address docker container by name when net="host"

Tags: docker, graylog2

I'm having some strange issues with docker's `--net="host"`

When deploying a container in a custom network, I can address it with it's name. But when specifying `--net="host"` instead of `--net="customnetwork"`, no ports are exposed, and I cannot address the container in any way. Here's the host network inspection

```
docker network inspect host
[
    {
        "Name": "host",
        "Id": "663f54513dc2b631d6f81457a49374da3bc3193ac0617497c018c47520600e22",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "host",
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": []
        },
        "Containers": {
            "836433bfa612f84fa3d73dec0f920e47affc529b64636f5e1bf38a8b7ced2d75": {
                "Name": "elasticsearch",
                "EndpointID": "79950c18d12d6c7a6715135287d48c7963bed21c7b09b28f6d443b7040eea697",
                "MacAddress": "",
                "IPv4Address": "",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "86d4bd0c232a350371131c300c417877e0fb0c54b831f85093b0d2228d9b4f1a": {
                "Name": "mongo",
                "EndpointID": "492022820dd1e0a634e63c97962575b0bffe1c137163cce4df30aa8da39d1159",
                "MacAddress": "",
                "IPv4Address": "",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e4b9179849afa529a6249b067c27953d0b187afdd5fac76112bb9b1369ae9556": {
                "Name": "graylog",
                "EndpointID": "e705eede1ddf897c8c4fc45ae6fcf77db8228b1a0c2d318f6045846e52951b93",
                "MacAddress": "",
                "IPv4Address": "",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {}
    }
]
```

As you can see, no IP addresses are assigned, and nothing changed anywhere.

I'm relatively new to docker, and maybe I missed something.

Some info regarding background:

I'm using docker to deploy graylog2. It references mongodb and elasticserach by their hostname, and needs to have the ability to listen to ports on the host to catch incoming log messages. The ports are configured post deployment.

Docker version: 1.10.3, build 20f81dd

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a `--net=host`, there is no separate network, there's no port to forward since it's just listening on your host (you can't forward to yourself, especially since you have the port in use), and there's no separate IP, it's the IP of your host.

Comment: So what I should do is use a bridge? So I can link the three containers? But what about the ports then? I should pre-determine a set of IP that will be used later?

Comment: When you use the built in bridge, containers can refer to each other by hostname and talk to any port on that container, think of the bridge as a VLAN. And you publish the ports that you wish to share from your host into your container, so others only need to know the IP of your host and the traffic will be NAT'ed into the proper service.